# What are Hash Tables, hash and key?

Tags: python

What are hash tables? Where is the hash in the hash table? Below explains what hash is calculated for the address of the value of the index. But we do not see any see hashes, instead a key is used.

> To access dictionary elements, you can use the familiar square
>   brackets along with the key to obtain its value.

```
# Declare a dictionary 
dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}

# Accessing the dictionary with its key
print "dict['Name']: ", dict['Name']
print "dict['Age']: ", dict['Age']
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_hash_table.htm

> Hash tables are a type of data structure in which the address or the
>   index value of the data element is generated from a hash function.
>   That makes accessing the data faster as the index value behaves as a
>   key for the data value. In other words Hash table stores key-value
>   pairs but the key is generated through a hashing function.
>
> So the search and insertion function of a data element becomes much
>   faster as the key values themselves become the index of the array
>   which stores the data.
>
> In Python, the Dictionary data types represent the implementation of
>   hash tables. The Keys in the dictionary satisfy the following
>   requirements.
>
> The keys of the dictionary are hashable i.e. the are generated by
>   hashing function which generates unique result for each unique value
>   supplied to the hash function. The order of data elements in a
>   dictionary is not fixed.

Comment: The hash itself in the table is usually abstracted away from the user/programmer. You should look at it purely as an implementation detail. You can use `__hash__` to implement your own hashing function for an object. If you want to know what's going on under the hood, you can see the [cpython implementation of dict](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c)

Answer (score 0):

The `__hash__` method is applied internally to the key you supply. You can override this function for classes you create. The default hashing function is implementation-dependent. You can see the CPython implementations (they appear to use different functions on different data types) [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/39d87b54715197ca9dcb6902bb43461c0ed701a2/Include/pyhash.h).

Comment: Just a clarification question: isn't the `__hash__` method applied to the value supplied and it _results_ in a key?

Comment: No. Values in hash tables don't get hashed, only keys. The result of hashing the key determines where in the table the value is stored, so it can be found by providing the key (which is again hashed to look it up).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!